# Open my console as default when running the Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, console

I am working on Eclipse plugin and for that I have need of communication with the console.
I have developed the console using this:

```java
public void openConsole() {

    MyConsole = createConsole1();

}

private IOConsole createConsole1() {

    //creating a console with title Welcome to SoC Console.
    IOConsole ioconsole = new IOConsole("Welcome to my Console.",null);

    //adding created console to console list in console view.
    ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager().addConsoles(new IConsole[] {ioconsole});
    ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager().showConsoleView(ioconsole);

   IOConsoleOutputStream OPstream = ioconsole.newOutputStream();
   try {
    OPstream.write("myConsole>");
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But after deploying it none of the console is visible in my plugin and message shows this:

```
No console to display at this time.
```

Now I need to open my console when I open the plugin instead of this.
help me if anyone know this.
Least help by you may help me a lot so please help.

Comment: Where have you put this code? Is it actually being run?

Comment: i have created createConsole1() method and called it in createConsole1()  inside the consoleFactory

Comment: That still does not tell us how you are running this code. Is it called from a menu item?

Comment: it is called when plugin is started..

Comment: If you mean the plugin activator 'start' method that is not run until something else in the plugin is used. It does **not** normally run during Eclipse start up.